# "Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key"

Tags: php, joomla

i have found the similar question, but not relevant answer. so asking twice.

I have generated an google api key. and using the same code in my joomla coding which was described in

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

but when i am running the code, it says, "Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key".

how to get rid of that?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to activate v3 of google maps in your control panel. After that create a new key and it should work

**From documentation**

> 3 Activate the Google Maps API v3 service.

Comment: thank you for spending your precious time to reply me. I have followed your instruction, still i am facing same problem. I have just copied the code of google map v3, then turned on v3 in the control panel and generated a key , and edited the "edit allowed refers" and then used the api key in my code. Still that code is saying the same problem.

Comment: thank you for spending your precious time to reply me. I have followed your instruction, still i am facing same problem.
 Can there be any problem with my website's address, which i am giving in "edit allowed refers"? i have given [link]"http://www.drive.itcslive.com" there. is it okay? the link where i placed the code is--->

http://drive.itcslive.com/joomla/hotelbay/index.php/search?view=hoteldetails

Comment: @user try to give access to any url to start, once it works try to limit to your domain only